# Generating a hash key using cpp

Tags: c++, hash

I was trying to generate hash keys for unsigned long long variables in cpp using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
using namespace std;
    unsigned long long pc[100];
    unsigned long long h[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
        pc[i] = i%50;
        hash<unsigned long long> hash_fn;
        h[i] = hash_fn(pc[i]);
        std::cout <<pc[i]<< "=" << h[i] << '\n';
        }
return 0;
}
```

But I ended up getting the same values I provided as inputs in the form of signature. Please let me know if I did any mistake. 
Here's the link I referred to to do this. 
[hashing function in cpp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Comment: You haven't made any mistake. Except possibly assuming that your output isn't expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to std::hash description at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> Notably, some implementations use trivial (identity) hash
>   functions which map an integer to itself. In other words, these hash
>   functions are designed to work with unordered associative containers,
>   but not as cryptographic hashes, for example.

Comment: No its not for cryptographic application, I have an unsigned long long pc which has to be converted to a signature of 14 bit size. So am trying to use this approach. Is it possible?

Comment: So you need to generate 14 bit signature value for unsigned long long values? It means that signatures won't be unique.

Comment: Yeah signatures need not be unique. But same number should get same signature every-time.

Comment: Perhaps it can be solved like this: `uint16_t signature = 0x3FFF & ( value % 16384 );` It generates 14 bit signature (range 0-16384) for each given `unsigned long long` value.

Comment: No its not like that. 2 numbers can have same signature but with a less probability. That is the reason I want to do hashing. Your method gives lot of repetitions.

Comment: @Brichkandy *"[pstanisz's] method gives lot of repetitions."* you only get "repetitions" if the input numbers are 16384 apart... is that a real concern?  If you want a stronger hash function, don't use your implementation's `std::hash`.  There are lots of questions on SO and post elsewhere online with hash function recommentations... even something as simple as `(n << 5) ^ (n >> 3)` - pick whatever numbers - may help.